# CSS Transition run slower on fill

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions

I have a class that change the color of a div and the fill of a svg, with a transition of 0.5s. But when I try it the transition on the fill was noticeable slower. I try to match it changing the transition of the element to  0.1469s. But its not perfect and kinda break the effect I was looking for.

```
.main-color{
    background-color: var(--main-dark-color);
    fill: var(--main-dark-color);
    color: var(--main-light-color);
    transition: all .5s;
}
.main-color.light {
    background-color: var(--main-light-color);
    fill: var(--main-light-color);
    color: var(--main-dark-color);
}
.svg{
    transition: all 0.1469s; /* This is the one running slower */
}
```

Any idea to fix this?

```js
const swapColor = document.querySelectorAll(".main-color");

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  swapColor.forEach(el => {
    el.classList.toggle("light");
  })
});
```

```css
.main-color {
  fill: red;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all 5s;
}

.main-color.light {
  fill: blue;
  background-color: red;
}

.parallax>use:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
  animation-duration: 30s;
}

@keyframes move-forever {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(85px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-color">
  <svg class="waves" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 24 150 28" preserveAspectRatio="none" shape-rendering="auto">
    <path x="1" y="7" id="gentle-wave" d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put enough code into your question so we can see the problem. In particular we need to see the svg. For help with doing this see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I made a version of it on codepen
https://codepen.io/rn4444/pen/gOvzPQP

Comment: I have run your codepen  and the fill and background color change take exactly the same time as far as I can see (I have tested it with a much longer transition time too). I am on Edge/Windows10 - what system/browser are you using?

Comment: I added your codepen as snippet directly, where exactly do you see any problems?

Comment: Sorry I was trying stuff and didnt realize I had autosave enabled. There I restore it to it original state.
Aparently the problem is caused by the defs. I gonna try to emulate the same shape without using them

Comment: EDIT: Was not the defs, the problem aparently is having the class that change the color on both, the div that holds the svg, and the svg itself. Apparently it fully changes the div color, and after that it changes the svg color